# Lists That Store Elements in Files

Tags: java, data-structures

Are there any Lists in java that store the elements in a file? I have a fairly memory intensive application and I would like something like this. Is it possible/has it been implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find anything like this in the standard libraries or in one of the commonly used frameworks.

A reasonable approach would probably be to use a database to back your data. There are some very lightweight databases like Derby and most JPA implementation can build the tables automatically, so you just need a persistence.xml and a JPA entity to hold your data.